# How to change NFC TX power from the Android phone application?

Tags: android, nfc

I want to write a simple application on Android that powers and reads data from an NFC tag.

Does the Android SDK provide an option to change the TX power of the NFC frontend of the phone?

Answer (score 1):

No, the Android API does not provide any means to change the TX power of the NFC transceiver.